# Peer review for resumes and job postings

Tags: discussion, feature-request

One of the ways Workplace SE could provide more value is by creating a platform to help employers and job candidates create high quality job postings and job applications, which will help candidates attract the best employers and employers attract the best candidates.

**The process:**

We attach an employer/candidate review site to Workplace SE and give it an appropriate name. Employers post job postings, and the community peer reviews them. They're not publicly available until they receive X number of +1 reviews and any edits are approved by the employer. Likewise, candidates post job applications that are also peer reviewed. Like the job postings, the applications cannot be submitted to employers until they receive a certain number of +1 reviews and any edits are approved by the applicant.

Once both job postings and applications are vetted, candidates with highly polished job applications then choose to apply for the highly polished job postings that best fits them.

The goal is to make the process of hiring an employee or finding a job be  quicker, since both the employer and candidate written materials will be the best they can be.

**Is this something that would work as an added feature on Workplace SE?**

See this [chat transcript between jmac and myself for more context](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/conversation/peer-review-for-resumes-and-job-postings).

Comment: Disclaimer on my comment: I have built things in this area and worked with organizations implementing similar discussion/crowdsourced review platforms for their localized use.  Comment #1: Isn't this antithetical to the Q&A nature of SE? Comment #2: If not, and it's envisioned like Code Review SE, wouldn't SE be more prudent to roll something related to this into Careers 2.0? (where, however, the traditional resume & job posting paradigm is subverted) Comment #3: sounds like a useful product, y'all should go build it. :)

Comment: @jcmeloni - I think we were picturing a separate site, like how careers.stackoverflow.com is separate. The Q&A site is a different beast altogether, and I think an experiment of this magnitude *in the Q&A section* would break the site.

Comment: @jcmeloni: `Isn't this antithetical to the Q&A nature of SE?` - Terrific point. Jeff Atwood is probably rolling over in his Discourse.org grave!

Comment: @JimG. - For sure. :) This stuff is really just loose, uninhibited brainstorming based on something [jmac said here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2083/98). This stuff definitely wouldn't fit as an actual topic on Workplace SE, not without really junking up the Q&A.